# How to switch to a particular version of Linux source code using git?

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel

Specifically, I want to switch to the kernel version 2.6.32.41 source code. However, in the output of

`git tag -l`

it shows the following:

v2.6.32-rc2
v2.6.32-rc3
v2.6.32-rc4
v2.6.32-rc5
v2.6.32-rc6
v2.6.32-rc7
v2.6.32-rc8

Which one of these is 2.6.32.41 linux kernel source?

Comment: +1 I had this question before and used for convenience a tar download.

Comment: "The updated 2.6.32.y git tree can be found at:
        git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/longterm/linux-2.6.32.y.git" http://lwn.net/Articles/444304/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of those tags are the 2.6.32.41 source.  The 2.6.x.* and 3.x.* versions are developed and maintained separately in the "stable" repository:

`git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git`

See https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git for the gitweb interface.

Comment: And [here are all the tags of the stable releases](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=tags)